# Replace the extreme value with percentile with DolphinDB update statement?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to replace the value in the perform column that is less than the 5th percentile with 5th percentile. Can I use the following to achieve?

```
update ljdata set perform=percentile(perform, 5) where perform<percentile(perform, 5)>
```

I have sample data percentile(perform, 5)=-15.77, but after executing this sentence, all the original values less than -15.77 are replaced by -61.38. How can I correct it? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
p5=exec percentile(perform, 5) from ljdata
update ljdata set perform=p5 where perform <p5
```

The problem is that `where` statement is executed before `update`. When the percentile is calculated, it is not the original data, but the remaining data involved in calculation.